# MySQL COUNT showing it's working out

Tags: php, mysql, count

I would expect the following to output the number "5", since there are 5 rows in the database with with item 68 and user 1. But instead I'm getting this output "12345".

```
$resultb4 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(comparedRating) FROM recComparedRating WHERE user1='1' AND itemID='68' GROUP BY itemID AND user1");
while($rowb4 = mysql_fetch_array($resultb4)){
    $countcomparedratings=$rowb4['COUNT(comparedRating)'];
}
echo $countcomparedratings;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting 12345 is because your query is returning 5 results and your code to output the count is simply outputting the concatenation of the returned array from the query.

Without understanding your database structure, I'm guessing that the reason you're getting the '12345' has something to do with your GROUP BY clause.  Use a program like MySQLWOrkbench to connect to your database and test out your query before you include it into your code.  It is a time saving technique to debug your queries.

Also, I would alias the COUNT value so that you simply refer to the alias when you refer to your column names.

```
SELECT COUNT(comparedRating) as ratingCount FROM recComparedRating WHERE user1='1' AND itemID='68' GROUP BY itemID AND user1");
```

Comment: It turned out that the problem was that it was running through each time inside a while loop. I moved the code above outside of that loop and it fixed it... that makes it sound simple but for reasons I can't remember/understand it took me days to fix.